# How to keep the user's private authentication data out of the model?

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication

I have a form like this:

```
<form ng-submit="loginFormSubmit()">
<label>
    Email address
    <input type="email" required ng-model="credentials.email">
</label>
<br>
<label>
    Password
    <input type="password" required ng-model="credentials.password">
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

How can I ensure that the `$scope.credentials` object is secure and inaccessible? Is there a way to not store the form fields' value in the model at all and simply grab their values when the submit function is called?

More generally, what are the best practices for handling sensitive form data in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has access to your model then they also have access to your DOM and `type="password"` can easily be changed to `type="text"` to view the value of the input box.

My recommendation is to be diligent and clear the model values as soon as you've submitted them to the server for verification. (or at least the password)